# Use TrackBar to Zoom In/out of Picturebox Proportionately

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox, trackbar

I'm using WinForms. In my form i have a picturebox that i want to zoom in and out using the track bar. My picturebox is set to zoom-mode. I want the image and picturebox to be proportion height/width when i drag the bar. How can i accomplish this?

```
    private void Open_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Image bmp;
            bmp = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            if (bmp == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Loading image failed", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
                openFileDialog1.Dispose();
            }

        }

    }

    private void zoomSlider_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(TrackBar1.Value == 1)
        {
            pictureBox1.Height += 50;
            pictureBox1.Width +=  50;

        }

        if(TrackBar1.Value == 2)
        {
            pictureBox1.Height += 100;
            pictureBox1.Width += 100;
        }

        if(TrackBar1.Value == 3)
        {
            pictureBox1.Height += 200;
            pictureBox1.Width += 200; 
        }

    //This is not exactly what i had in mind...
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When the form is originally created you have to save the size

```
Form1 : Form
{
   private Size _pictOriginalSize;
   Form1()
   {
       InitialiseComponent();
       _pictOriginalSize = pictureBox1.Size;
       zoomSlider.Minimum = 0;
       zoomSldier.Maximum = 1000;
       ...
   }
```

Now you know what it's *unzoomed* size was.

Next you will need to you will need to convert the value of the slider into into a scale factor.

```
private void zoomSlider_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const double MaxScale = 5.0; // The scale factor when the is at it's max

    double scale = Math.Pow(MaxScale, TrackBar1.Value / TrackBar1.Maximum);

    Size newSize = new Size((int) (_pictOrignalSize.Width * scale),
                   (int) (_pictOrignalSize.Height * scale));

    pictureBox.Size = newSize;
}
```

I am using the `Math.Pow` function to convert the scale from 1 to 5 on an exponential scale - you may want to use a different technique you could consider

- having the slider have values 1 to 5 and the Value simply becomes the scale: `scale = zoomSlider.Value` - but this only gives you a resoultion of 1.
- having the slider have values 1 to 5000 and do a double division `double scale = zoomSlider.Value / 1000.0;` This gives you a 1000 different resolutions.

NB: I am using 5 as an example only - you can use any value for the max scale factor.

Comment: Thank you Ubercoder, I implemented this into my code it works almost. The thing i want to do is as you drag the image gets bigger or smaller. Currently the image only gets big once and small once. Big when it reaches its max and small when its at value 0.